# ExtJS 4.0 cannot read connect.sid from cookie

Tags: cookies, extjs, state, connect, sid

I try do develop a web application with ExtJs 4.0.

On startup the application sends a request to a server. This server sends a response. The responses' header contains `Set-Cookie:"connect.sid=foobar"`

When I look into the preferences of my browser, I can see that the cookie was created correctly.

My problem is that somehow I cannot access this cookie in my ExtJs application and I don't know why.

I tried to retrieve it with the following methods:

- `document.cookie.split(";")[0]`
- `Ext.state.Manager.get("connect.sid");` => of course I initialized the state manager with a cookie provider
- `Ext.util.Cookies.get("connect.sid");`

No matter which method I use, I get always `undefined` as return value

I hope somebody can help me, because I really don't understand why it does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way all the cookies I create by using Ext.state.Manager.set("key","value") are readable for the state manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.

The `httpOnly` flag was set in the response header. Therefore the cookie was not accessible for java script.

Comment: I am having the same problem. How can I check the httpOnly flag?